# set jdk 6 but receive Error:java:invalid source release 8

Tags: java, intellij-idea, compilation

Java-multumodule project.  I changed jdk from 8 to 6.

And started receiving error:java:invalid source release 8

My settings:

[image: jdk61]

[image: jdk62]

[image: jdk63]
[image: jdk64]
[image: jdk65]

Comment: Maybe also set maven compiller plugin java version to 1.6.
https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/set-compiler-source-and-target.html

Comment: If you're using Gradle also check that `Gradle JVM` is configured correctly. `(Preferences | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Gradle | Gradle JVM)`